# AEM Dispatcher Cache Rule s

Tags: caching, aem, dispatcher

I want to add a cache rule that cache a multiple extensions with a given url/path.

Sample:

```
/rules

  /0100
  {
   /url "/urlpath/*"
   /type "allow"
   /extension '(json|xml|html|clientlibs|css|gif|ico|js|png|swf|jpe?g|woff2?)'
  }
```

Is this valid?

Comment: Why don't you just try it on your apache? Costs 2 minutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must follow the requirements for [specifying documents to cache](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html#specifying-the-documents-to-cache):

> Each item in the /rules property includes a glob pattern and a type:
>
> ```
> The glob pattern is used to match the path of the document.
> The type indicates whether to cache the documents that match the glob pattern. 
> The value can be either allow (to cache the document) or
> deny (to always render the document).
> ```

It looks like you're trying to use the syntax for [filter rules](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html#regular-expressions) in the cache section.  I think you'll need to use a glob pattern that matches the URL and extension using wildcards, so you may need to use multiple rules.